# Collapsing multiple rows by unique identifier, multiple values (columns), multiple elements per variable (rows)

Tags: r, aggregate, csv

I am trying to collapse multiple rows by unique identifier in R, but each column could have multiple variables that I want to keep in separate rows. How do I do that? I've tried the "separate_rows" function, but it says that each of the nested columns must have the same number of elements. Mine don't.

```
## Example1 start
sample_A.1 <- c ("sample_A", "","D","")
sample_A.2 <- c("sample_A", "","D","")    
sample_A.3 <- c("sample_A", "","","red")    
sample_B.1 <- c("sample_B", 28, "", "")
sample_B.2 <- c("sample_B", "", "D", "")
sample_B.3 <- c("sample_B", "", "N", "")
sample_B.4 <- c("sample_B", "", "", "orange")
sample_C.1 <- c("sample_C", 27, "", "")
sample_C.2 <- c("sample_C", 32, "", "")
sample_C.3 <- c("sample_C", "", "E", "")
sample_C.4 <- c("sample_C", "", "", "orange")
sample_C.5 <- c("sample_C", "", "", "yellow")
sample_C.6 <- c("sample_C", "", "", "green")
my.data <- data.frame(rbind(sample_A.1,sample_A.2,sample_A.3,sample_B.1,sample_B.2,sample_B.3,sample_B.4,sample_C.1,sample_C.2,sample_C.3,sample_C.4,sample_C.5,sample_C.6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(my.data) <- c("identifier", "var1", "var2", "var3")

# identifier   var1   var2   var3
# sample_A     30
# sample_A            D
# sample_A                   red
# sample_B     28
# sample_B            D
# sample_B            N
# sample_B                   orange
# sample_C     27
# sample_C     32
# sample_C            E
# sample_C                   orange
# sample_C                   yellow
# sample_C                   green

## Or

## Example2 start
sample_A <- c("sample_A", 30, "D", "red")
sample_B <- c("sample_B", 28, "D, N", "orange")
sample_C <- c("sample_C", "27, 32", "E", "orange, yellow, green")
my.data2 <- data.frame(rbind(sample_A, sample_B, sample_C), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(my.data2) <- c("identifier", "var1", "var2", "var3")

# identifier   var1   var2   var3
# sample_A     30     D      red
# sample_B     28     D, N   orange
# sample_C     27, 32 E      orange, yellow, green
```

To get from Example1 to Example2 above I used the following code (needs plyr or dplyr)...

```
library(dplyr)
my.data2a <- my.data %>% group_by(identifier) %>%
    summarize_all(funs(paste(.[!is.na(.)], collapse = " ")))
my.data2 <- data.frame(lapply(my.data2a, trimws), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
my.data2[2:4] <- sapply(my.data2[2:4], gsub, pattern=" ", replacement=", ")
```

I tried using the following code to melt the data in my.data2 into separate rows...(needs tidyr and tibble)

```
data2colnames <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
my.data2 %>% separate_rows(data2colnames)
```

But I got the error: "Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements." I need to get to the "End with" table in "example output" link above which basically looks like this:

```
identifier  var1  var2  var3
sample_A    30    D     red
sample_B.1  28    D     orange
sample_B.2        N
sample_C.1  27    E     orange
sample_C.2  32          yellow
sample_C.3              green
```

Comment: Please include representative (minimal) sample data in a copy & paste-able format (e.g. use `dput`). Also show your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: Indeed, it would be good if you provide a representative sample so that we can narrow down the issue. You could also include your code where you tried to tackle the problem so that we can elaborate on that if relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried something ugly. there must be something prettier.

```
library(purrr)
df=my.data
df[df==""]=NA

x= df %>% split(.$identifier) %>% map(function(x)sapply(x, function(y)sort(unique(y),dec=T)))
xx=map_dfr(x, function(x){
    mx=max(sapply(x, length))
    z=lapply(x, function(y){
        if(length(y)>0 & startsWith(y[1],"sample")){
            c(y,rep(y[1], mx-length(y)))
        }else
            c(y,rep("", mx-length(y)))
    })  
}) %>% as.data.frame

nm=xx$identifier
xx$identifier = unlist(lapply(split(nm,nm), function(x)if(length(x)>1)paste0(x,".",1:length(x)) else x ))

xx
```

Comment: Ugly can still be beautiful, especially with this case. It worked perfectly! Thank you. I only wish I could up your vote count, but I'm not above a 15 on my reputation. :/ Now for me to study what you coded so that I continue learning what it all means. If anyone has additional key words I can add to this post to help others in similar situations find this answer, please let me know. Thanks again! And I'll continue checking back for other solutions to learn them too.